# How to adjust subplots borders in matplotlib automatically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting multiple plots using `plt.subplots`, most of the time the spacing between subplots is not ideal so the the xtick labels of the top plot would overlap with the title of the bottom plots. There is a way to fix this manually by calling say `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)` and changing the parameters *interactively* to obtain a decent looking plot. Is there a way to calculate the `subplot_adjust` parameter automatically? Meaning finding the minimum `hspace` and `wspace` so that there is not overlap between texts of the plots.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that the closest your going to find to an inbuilt calculation method is:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

or

```
figure.Figure.tight_layout() #if you are using the object version of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tight_layout https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html or constrained_layout https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html